# Why does loading data into a Meteor Collection take so long?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, meteor

I'm trying to build a data visualization application using Meteor to visualize a large dataset. The data is currently stored in a CSV-format data file, and is about 64MB.

I'm using the node-csv plugin to load this data file into a Meteor Collection (code below).  But it's taking about 1 minute per 10k records, which at that rate will take about 1.5 hours to load the whole file into the Collection. During that time, the Meteor server is unresponsive to web requests.

This seems abnormally slow to me.  Is this normal?  Is Meteor just not designed to handle moderately large amounts of data? Or is there a better way to do this data-import process than the way I discovered?

```
var csv = Meteor.require('CSV');
var fs = Meteor.require('fs');
var path = Npm.require('path');

function loadData() {
  var basepath = path.resolve('.').split('.meteor')[0];
  console.log('Loading data into Meteor...');

  csv().from.stream(
    fs.createReadStream(basepath+'server/data/enron_data.csv'),
      {'escape': '\\'})
    .on('record', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(row, index) {
      if ((index % 10000) == 0) {
        console.log('Processing:', index, row);
      }
      Emails.insert({
        'sender_id': row[0],
        'recipient_id': row[1],
        'recipient_type': row[2],
        'date': row[3],
        'timezone': row[4],
        'subject': row[5]
        })
      }, function(error) {
          console.log('Error in bindEnvironment:', error);
      }
    ))
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('Error reading CSV:', err);
    })
    .on('end', function(count) {
      console.log(count, 'records read');
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd imagine that not using collections and accessing the DB directly would be much faster. That being said, I need more information to give you a real anser. When are you running `loadData`? e.g. is this initialization code for your local dev database? Have you removed the `autopublish` package?

Comment: You should use direct batch import, rather than inserting rows one by one. On some DBs you can temporarily disable constraints, indexing, etc., and wait with that until the last record has been batch-imported. This may mean one or two orders of magnitude speed-up.

Comment: @DavidWeldon it's in the Meteor.startup() part of a local dev server. Even with autopublish removed, it's still taking the same amount of time.

Comment: @TFuto can you tell me how to do that with Meteor/MongoDB/NodeCSV?  I would normally do a batch import if I could, but the only interface I can find for Meteor+CSV uses a row-by-row callback.

Comment: Consider giving a callback to the insert function.  "On the server, if you don't provide a callback, then insert blocks until the database acknowledges the write, or throws an exception if something went wrong." - http://docs.meteor.com#insert

Comment: Tessa: Are you sure all publish activity is disabled in the moment of import? I was recently dealing with a similar issue which I was able to solve by pausing data syncing between client and server. I was then able to import 3000 records in a split second. See my solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487873/meteor-collection-fetching-too-slow/19599079#19599079. Does this help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you do this outside of the meteor environment, loading your data one row at a time is really inefficient. I think the tool you want is [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

It may not be obvious, but you do not need to insert your documents with meteor in order to use meteor with your documents.

You can try calling mongoimport from `Meteor.startup` when there are 0 documents in your collection (or whatever base condition make sense in your situation). I haven't tried this so I can't say how much of a pain this is, but I'd imagine you could just call `child_process.spawn` to start mongoimport. If for some reason that doesn't work you could always put it in a script and run that script whenever you do a `meteor reset`.

Side note - I believe the appropriate place for your static server assets is the `private` directory. This also lets you use the [Assets](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets) api to access those files.

Comment: Thank you, `mongoimport` works perfectly. I didn't realize I could import data outside of the Meteor environment, but that's obviously the right solution.