# Bulk create in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I need to create 2000 documents at once in Meteor. I know I can use

```
for (i=0; i<2000; i++) {
    CollectionName.insert({});
}
```

but I hope there is a bulk create function in Meteor. How can I insert these 2000 rows in the fastest way possible?

Comment: you way is correct. If you want a bulk then see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757434/bulk-mongodb-insert-in-meteor-or-node

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.markdrew.co.uk/blog/post.cfm/importing-json-into-a-meteor-mongo-database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meteor doesn't natively support this. However, it does give you access to the node Mongodb driver which can natively do a bulk insert.

You can only do this on the server:

```
var x = new Mongo.Collection("xxx");

x.rawCollection.insert([doc1, doc2, doc3...], function(err, result) {
    console.log(err, result)
});
```

Or with MongoDB 2.6 if your Meteor instance has access to it:

```
var bulk = x.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.insert( { _id: 1, item: "abc123", status: "A", soldQty: 5000 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 2, item: "abc456", status: "A", soldQty: 150 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 3, item: "abc789", status: "P", soldQty: 0 } );
bulk.execute( { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } );
```

Notes:

- This is not synchronous or isn't run in a fiber as it uses the raw node driver. You need to use Meteor.bindEnvironment or Meteor.wrapAsync to create synchronous code
- The documents are inserted unordered and may not be in the original order you added them in.
- It may take 10 seconds for Meteor to see the documents 'Reactively' through a publish method if your instance is not oplog enabled.

Answer (score 5):

Extending @Akshat's answer, this is the syntax that would work on Meteor 1.0+

```
x = new Mongo.Collection("x");
var bulk = x.rawCollection().initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

bulk.insert( { _id: 1, item: "abc123", status: "A", soldQty: 5000 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 2, item: "abc456", status: "A", soldQty: 150 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 3, item: "abc789", status: "P", soldQty: 0 } );

Meteor.wrapAsync(bulk.execute)();
```

Comment: One thing that was tripping me up: if you have ObjectIDs that you're trying to insert, you need to convert them to Node's representation of ObjectID rather than Meteor's when inserting into a raw collection.`MongoInternals.NpmModule.ObjectID(your_obj_id._str);`

Comment: For me, it threw an error then I have added the context as second parameter, so it worked. `Meteor.wrapAsync(bulk.execute, bulk)();`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use:

`/server/fixtures.js`

```
var insertIntoCollection = function(collection, dataArray){
  dataArray.forEach(function(item){
    collection.insert(item);
  });
};

if (Stuff.find().count() === 0) {

  var array = [
    { 
      // document1
    },{
      // document2
    }
  ];

  insertIntoCollection(Stuff, array);
};
```

Comment: Easy solution. Meteor 1.4 will have Mongo 3.2 with Bulk Insert. If you don't have 10,000 documents this solution will work very nicely.